# SQL Server 2008 R2 : Merge Query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-merge

I am using the following syntax for a `merge` :

```
MERGE INTO studentinfo as Target
USING StudentInfo_Temp as Source ON Target.Form Number = Source.Form Number

WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET Target.Form Number = Source.Form Number

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ([Form Number], [Academic Program]) 
   VALUES (Source.Form Number, Source.Academic Program);
```

But I am getting an error above on the line

```
on Target.Form Number = Source.Form Number
```

If I replace this by Taget.ID = Source.ID it works fine so I am assuming I have to write a column with a space in name some other way.

Any suggestion on the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use brackets to enclose the values with spaces:

```
Target.[Form Number] = Source.[Form Number]
```

see the section for *Delimited identifiers* in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Oh Thank you , i was doing it like [Target.Form Number ] :).

Comment: @confusedMind Using double-quotes should work too (it's what the ANSI standard uses if memory serves me right, but brackets seem to be the default for T-SQL devs in my experience).